# Why did Paul change the word order of "retribution" and "trap" from Psalm 69:22?

Tags: psalms, romans

> NIV Psalm 69:22
> May their table become a **snare**; may it be a **retribution** and a **trap**.

> Romans 11:9
> And David says: "May their table become a **snare** and a **trap**, a stumbling block and a **retribution** for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rom 11:9 is a good example of the way that Paul quotes the OT in a "creative" way and feels free, under divine inspiration, to modify the OT text.  [Note: I will not be using the NIV here as it is not a good rendering of the Hebrew, so I have below, chosen the version that best reflects the Hebrew.]

**Hebrew** of Ps 69:22 [NKJV] -

> Let their table become a **snare** before them, And their well-being a
> **trap**.

**Septuagint** of Ps 69:22 [Swete and Brenton] -

> Let their table before them be for a **snare**, and for a **recompense**, and
> for a **stumbling-block**

**Paul** in Rom 11:9 -

> And David says: "Let their table be for a **snare** and for a
> **trap**, and for a **stumbling block** and for a **retribution** to them.

Notice the steady growth in the text:

- The Hebrew only has **snare** and **trap** in classic Hebrew synthetic parallelism
- The Greek LXX has **snare**, and **recompense**, and **stumbling-block**
- Paul "quotes" this as: **snare**, and **trap**, and **stumbling-block**, and **retribution**.

This kind of use of the OT is common by the NT writers.  Paul appears to paraphrase the Hebrew and then add a second part to the original verse that is even greater than the already expanded LXX.

Moderns might object to such "sloppiness" with the OT sacred text, but Paul, under divine inspiration, felt free to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The differences and similarities between the [Septuagint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septuagint) and Paul are as follows:

> γενηθήτω ἡ τράπεζα αὐτῶν **ἐνώπιον αὐτῶν**
> εἰς παγίδα
> καὶ εἰς `ἀνταπόδοσιν` καὶ εἰς `σκάνδαλον`

> γενηθήτω ἡ τράπεζα αὐτῶν
> εἰς παγίδα **καὶ εἰς θήραν**
> καὶ εἰς `σκάνδαλον` καὶ εἰς `ἀνταπόδομα` **αὐτοῖς**

Personally, I am not inclined to think that there is any intentional choice or conscious reason for the various small differences between the two texts.